# Rails Controllers and Subscriptions to Website Features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## Context

I've got this application that runs off subscriptions to specific apps within the website.

I want to be able to keep adding apps, and as such, I've got an `App` model.

Many models are necessary for a specific feature, which translates into a couple controllers as well.

## Example

Let's say I've got a classified ads feature, an `App` row with the name `classified_ads`, a `ClassifiedAd` model and a `ClassifiedCategory` model and controllers for everything except `App`.

## Problem

The issue I'm faced with is that I want to know in what app using at all times.

I've tried many solutions, but I'm looking for a scalable solution specifically.

Currently, after many very different attempts, the best solution I came up with is a controller concern called `CurrentApp`.

```
module CurrentApp
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    helper_method :current_app
  end

  def current_app
    case params[:controller]
    when /classified_ads/, /classified_category/
      App.find_by_name :classified_ads
    when /etc/
      App.find_by_name :etc
  end

end
```

I'd rather something that is automated and scales.

I've already tried something like defining a method `app` for the models, but doesn't scale well at all due to coupling with the name. I'd rather just keep the mess within a single file.

I've also been looking into a `belongs_to` relationship and adding a foreign key to each model that relates to an app. Though, I think that this would actually help considering that I need to know where I am even without a model.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would truly appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to derive `:classified_ads` from `classified_category` without a lookup table.  You could create a Lookup class, a PORO in your initializers

```
#app/config/initializers/lookup.rb

class Lookup

  LOOKUP = {
            classified_categories_controller: :classified_ads,
            classified_ads_controller: :classified_ads,
            some_other_controller: :other_app
           }

  def self.app(controller)
    LOOkUP[controller.to_sym]
  end

end
```

Then in your controllers you can do....

```
App.find_by_name(Lookup.app(params[:controller])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this cleans up my `current_app` concern a lot! I will still look for a way to automate things as I have many namespaces, including an api, and at the least 35 controllers. However, I feel like you've laid out the right direction, thank you again.